# Surface integral help

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Calculate surface integral:

$\iint_{\Sigma} \frac{\mathrm{d} S}{z}$

$\Sigma$:The top of a sphere ($x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=a^{2}$) cut by a plane ($z = h  (0<h<a)$)

My code:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
reg = ImplicitRegion[\!\(TraditionalForm\`
\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)] + 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(y\), \(2\)] + 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(z\), \(2\)] == 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(a\), \(2\)]\) && z >= h && a > 0 && 0 < h < a, {x, 
    y, z}];
f[x_, y_, z_] := 1/z
Integrate[f[x, y, z], Element[{x, y, z}, reg]]

(* Integrate returns unevaluated. *)
```

Even if I assign values to all variables:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
reg = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1 && z > 1/2, {x, y, z}];
f[x_, y_, z_] := 1/z
Integrate[f[x, y, z], Element[{x, y, z}, reg]]

(* Integrate returns unevaluated. *)
```

If I use spherical coordinates by use ParametricRegion and with a=1, h=1/2, I can get a result:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
reg = ParametricRegion[{Cos[ϕ]*Sin[θ], 
    Sin[ϕ]*Sin[θ], 
    Cos[θ]}, {{ϕ, 0, 2 π}, {θ, 0, 
     ArcCos[1/2]}}];
f[x_, y_, z_] := 1/z
Integrate[f[x, y, z], Element[{x, y, z}, reg]]


(*π Log[4]*)
```

However, if a and h are not assigned, the result cannot be obtained:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
reg = ParametricRegion[{r*Cos[ϕ]*Sin[θ], 
    r*Sin[ϕ]*Sin[θ], 
    r*Cos[θ]}, {{ϕ, 0, 2 π}, {r, a, a}, {θ, 0, 
     ArcCos[h/a]}}];
f[x_, y_, z_] := 1/z
Integrate[f[x, y, z], Element[{x, y, z}, reg], 
 Assumptions -> a > 0 && 0 < h < a]

(* Doesn't finish calculating in 500 seconds. *)
```

Comment: Do you expect this integral has a closed form for symbolic parameters a and h? As a start, try specifying exact numerical values for a and h to see how complicated the expression is. E.g., a=1 and h=1/2.

Comment: Also failed. @tad

Comment: @lotus2019 Your second approach using `NIntegrate` works!

Comment: Thank you. If I use ParametricRegion with a=1, h=1/2, I can get a result.  But if a and h are not assigned, the result cannot be obtained. @Ulrich Neumann

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for numerical result as function of `a,h` try

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := 1/z
intN[a_?NumericQ, h_?NumericQ] :=NIntegrate[f[x, y, z],Element[{x, y, z}, ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == a^2 && h < z < a, {x,y, z}] ]]

intN[1,1/2] (*4.35517*)
```

**addendum**

Analytical solution (spherical coordinates) evalutes too

```
int[a_ , h_ ] =Integrate[f[a Cos[\[CurlyPhi]] Sin[ \[Theta]], a Sin[\[CurlyPhi]] Sin[ \[Theta]], a Cos[ \[Theta]]] a^2 Sin[\[Theta]], {\[CurlyPhi], 0, 2 Pi}, {\[Theta], 0, ArcCos[h/a]}, Assumptions -> a > h > 0]    
(*-2 a \[Pi] Log[h/a]*)
```

and agrees with the numerical solution

```
int[1,1/2]//N (*4.35517*)
```

Comment: Great answer! That's exactly what I want. Thanks a lot! @Ulrich Neumann